# Need help making a sub menu that opens on hover

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, submenu

I have a menu that I have built that is currently working fine, I am trying to add sub menu items that appear when the mouse hovers over a menu item. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<div id="menu">
            <a  href="#" >Home</a>
            <a  href="#">Submit New Record</a>
            <a   href="#">Sales by Salesperson</a>
            <a   href="#">Total Sales</a>
            <a  href="#" >Sales by Issue</a>
            <a  href="#" >Sales by Ad Size</a> 
            <a  href="#" >Add New User</a>  
            <a href="#">Edit Record</a> 
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
            </div></center>
<style>
#menu{
background-color:#3F9AD1;
height:75px;
width:1206px;
}

#menu a{
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color:white;
padding-top: 20px;
float:left;
display:block;
width:130px;
height:70px;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
text-align:center;
font-family: Arial;
/*box-shadow: 0 -7px 22px 6px #000000 inset;*/
}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#3F9AD1;
    background-color:white;

#html { 
height: 100%; 
margin-bottom: 0.01em;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: Have you googled anything? "html5 hover menu" gives about 2,000,000 hits, this one looks nice: http://jacwright.github.io/simpli5/demos/hover-menu.html

Answer (score 3):

I normally do that like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Main Menu Item
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the css like this:

```
ul.submenu {
    display: none;
}

li:hover ul.submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go here and learn using their sample tutorial. It's quite easy. Just deals with you hover state.

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu